# Unable to rotate AVPlayerViewController when fullscreen

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

The app I am working on has `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` set as `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`.

I create an AV player like so:

```
let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
// Some AVPlayer input
playerVC.player = player
presentableViewController?.present(playerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The `AVPlayerViewController` works however when I enter fullscreen and try to rotate it remains fixed to `portrait`. I need the ability to rotate to landscape.

I tried subclassing `AVPlayerViewController` like so:

```
class AVPlayerViewControllerRotatable: AVPlayerViewController {
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        .all
    }
}
```

However this had no effect. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "The app has UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait set as UISupportedInterfaceOrientations" Which means that no view controller can ever rotate to landscape. The app interface orientations state all the orientations that any view controller can ever assume.

Comment: @matt so if I only want a single view controller to support landscape is my only option allowing `all` in the `plist` and manually turning off rotate for all the view controllers that I don't want to rotate?